# How can we compare the following big O notations since they all are O(X^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was comparing certain big O notations and noticed that we usually ignore the constants. Does this hold true for the following case as well?
`O(5^3n)` `O(15^n)` `O(5^n)` `O(5^3n+5)` `O(3^5n)`

According to the hypothesis then all of these should be equal but do the values 5, 15 and 3 create a difference?

Comment: Use the definition of Big-O.

Comment: Is your fourth one `5^(3n + 5)` or `(5^3n) + 5`?  Parentheses are important for removing ambiguity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion "we usually ignore the constants" it's not true. Or maybe it's incomplete.

O notation is an approximation.

You can ignore every addend that increases slower.

So:

O(n+4) is O(n)

O(n^2 + n) is O(n^2)

It's to avoid complicated calculus in complexity computation that doesn't give additional information to improve algorithm.

Comment: SO according to this the order should go like 3^5n, 5^n, 5^3n=5^3n+5, 15^n

Comment: O notation is a bound, not an approximation. If something grows linearly, it's legitimate to say it's O(n^2) or O(2^n) as well, even though we generally prefer to use tight bounds.